# How to use a local file with golang using Now (zeit.co)?

Tags: go, vercel

I'm creating an api with golang and [zeit-now](https://zeit.co/). I want the API to return a password generated from a list of words (30k). Everything works if I use a local server (*http.ListenAndServe*), but when I try to access the concerned endpoint with the [now link](http://api-git-dev.komfy.now.sh/randDict), an error occurs.

I tried to use the [config.includeFiles](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/builders/overview/?query=includeFiles#including-additional-files) option, but it doesn't work. I also tried to use local path, absolute path but nothing is working.

Here is the now.json and randDict.go files:

**now.json**

```
"builds": [
            {
                "src": "/lambdas/randDict/randDict.go",
                "use": "@now/go",
                "config": {
                    "includeFiles": [
                        "template/wordsGist"
                    ]
                }
            }
]
```

**randDict.go**

```golang
// Create a slice with the words from the words' file
func createWordsSlice() ([]string, int, error) {
    // Read all the words inside the file "wordsGist"
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("template/wordsGist")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, 0, err
    }
    // Split the words into a slice
    words := strings.Split(string(file), "\n")
    return words, len(words), nil

}
```

Here I expect a slice with all the words, which I'll be using later for password generation, but I get an error and a empty slice (nil).

Here is the [github](https://www.github.com/komfy/api/tree/dev) if you want to read all the code.

Comment: "I get an error" - what is the error?

Comment: @Adrian Sorry for that... I get a 502: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA because in the function that generate the password I use rand.Intn and when I get an error in createWordsSlice I return zero so my program panics...